# How to change point size or shape in FastScatterPlot (JFreeChart)?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a large collection of 2D coordinates (i.e., easily in the order of 100k to 200k x,y pairs) that I would like to visualize as a scatter plot. For the application that this is intended for, having so many points makes sense and I can't/won't reduce the number for different reasons. To plot this in Java, I use JFreeChart. I have played around with `ChartFactory.createScatterPlot()` and 50k randomly generated points, and while this gives the greatest amount of flexibility to set the appearance (point size/color/shape), it is slow for displaying many points. That means, it takes some time to appear and zooming is also delayed/not smooth. However, once only few points are actually visible, i.e., deeply zoomed in, the visualization is nicely responsive.

On the contrary, `FastScatterPlot()` allows to easily draw 500k randomly generated 2D points but the appearance is not really nice as I managed only to set the color so far (using, e.g., `setPaint(Color.BLUE)`) but not the shape or the size. The size is a problem in particular as the individual points are really small.

How can I change the point size or shape in `FastScatterPlot`?

And related to this, is there a way to make the chart returned by `ChartFactory.createScatterPlot()` more responsive?

My data is fixed and the rendering must principally not necessarily change during runtime hence if there are ways to disconnect any listeners or such to improve performance, this would also be an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For speed, you might try the alternate [`FastScatterPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/FastScatterPlot.html) calculation suggested in the [`render()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/FastScatterPlot.html#render-java.awt.Graphics2D-java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D-org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo-org.jfree.chart.plot.CrosshairState-) method's [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/FastScatterPlot.html#line.572) comments; [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to compare. For size, you can change the rendered size in the same method; the following would quadruple the size of each point.

```
g2.fillRect(transX, transY, 2, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I get this right that, instead of `fillRect()` I could also use other functions, such as `fillOval()` to represent different shapes? Of course, I would have to modify/extend the `FastScatterPlot` class then. And colors could be used, e.g., by `g2.setPaint(Color.RED);` for red shapes? Is it possible to cycle through a set of colors and have distinct sets of points in distinct colors or is it only possible to use exactly one color for all points?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the hint by **trashgod**, I decided to simply extend `FastScatterPlot` in the following way. You can now specify the colors, sizes and shapes in the constructor of `ExtendedFastScatterPlot` and it works very nicely for 500k points. Using `fillOval()` for half of the points seems to slow down things when compared to using `fillRect()` for all the points but that is not really an issue as long as the plot is overall acceptably responsive. And it is now much more responsive compared to `XYPlot`. Little effort, great value!

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CrosshairState;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.FastScatterPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge;

public class ExtendedFastScatterPlot extends FastScatterPlot {

   /**
    *
    */
   private static final long    serialVersionUID    = 1L;

   int[] sizes;
   Paint[] colors;
   int[] shapes;

   public ExtendedFastScatterPlot(float[][] data, NumberAxis domainAxis, NumberAxis rangeAxis, int[] sizes, Paint[] colors, int[] shapes) {
       super(data,domainAxis,rangeAxis);
       this.sizes = sizes;
       this.colors = colors;
       this.shapes = shapes;
   }

   @Override
   public void render(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D dataArea, PlotRenderingInfo info, CrosshairState crosshairState) {
       //g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);

       if (this.getData() != null) {
           for (int i = 0; i < this.getData()[0].length; i++) {
               float x = this.getData()[0][i];
               float y = this.getData()[1][i];
               int size = this.sizes[i];
               int transX = (int) this.getDomainAxis().valueToJava2D(x, dataArea, RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
               int transY = (int) this.getRangeAxis().valueToJava2D(y, dataArea, RectangleEdge.LEFT);
               g2.setPaint(this.colors[i]);
               if( 1 == this.shapes[i])
               {
                   g2.fillRect(transX, transY, size, size);
               }
               else
               {
                   g2.fillOval(transX, transY, size, size);
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```